# How to pass scalar parameter to a metal kernel function?

Tags: metal

I am new to metal. I want to use metal compute to do some math, so I create a kernel function (shader?), let's say

```
    kernel void foo(device float *data1,
                    device float *data2,
                    device float *result,
                    int flag,
                    uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]])
    {
      if(flag==SOMETHING)
      {
      }...
    }
```

Any idea to encode a scalar value to the `flag` parameter in `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are already doing it. There isn't much difference between a `void*` buffer with "arbitrary" data and an `int`.

Juse make the binding a `device` or `constant` (since it's a flag I would assume `constant` is more suitable) address space reference and decorate if with `[[ buffer(n) ]]` attribute for better readability (and other buffer bindings also), so your new function signature is gonna look like

```
kernel void foo(device float *data1 [[buffer(0)]],
                device float *data2 [[buffer(1)]],
                device float *result [[buffer(2)]],
                device int& flag [[buffer(3)]],
                uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]])
```

As for the encoder, you can use `setBuffer` or `setBytes` on your `MTLComputeCommandEncoder` but basically, the easiest way to do this would be

```
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> encoder = ...
// ...
int flag = SomeFlag | SomeOtherFlag
[encoder setBytes:&flag length:sizeof(flag) atIndex:3];
```